Is "its complexity is often more seeming than substantial" natural?
From [Joseph M. Williams. (1990). Style: Toward Clarity and Grace. p.xi]

Difficult a passage may be, but its complexity is often more seeming
than substantial.

Oxford Learner's Dictionaries and LONGMAN say 'seeming' is only before noun.
Is this usage natural?

Not all dictionaries require 'seeming' (adjective) to be followed by a noun; 'more seeming than real' is a fairly common phrase.

seeming can be used as a synonym for apparent but that sense had its heyday in the 19th century and earlier.

Difficult a passage may be ...

is also a construction that has been gathering dust.
